# How can I access photo folder in other asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on two asp.net projects.
First project is for employees to manage products informations.

Second project is for product sales website.
My problem is, in first project when an employee inserts product photo, this goes to folder in first project named "Photos" and path will be inserted to db. But how can I access to this folder from my second project?
(first's domain will be admin.sampleXYZ.com
second's will be sampleXYZ.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not store the photos in the first project, I would store them in the place they are needed - so in your product sales website project. 
To achieve this you should take advantage of Virtual Directories:

> In computing, the term virtual directory has a couple of meanings. It
>   may simply designate (for example in IIS) a folder which appears in a
>   path but which is not actually a subfolder of the preceding folder in
>   the path.

So what I would do is to add a virtual directory in your first project pointing to a physical directory in your second project ([you can set it on IIS level](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

In case of large volumes of photos I would recommend to store your photos outside the scope of any of these two projects. In such case it is better to have a separate FTP server and store your photos there and not pollute the content of your projects (which should contain the code, not become a content container).

Comment: First I would like to thank you. I m middle level developer so should i try your way or simple way is to inserting photos to db as binary data and get them from each projects.

Comment: In case you won't have thousands of photos you can try to store them in the DB. It is not the performance-wise way, but ni your case probably the quickest one.